# Swap operations and boot are much slower in Windows than in Mac OS

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, swap, swap-file

I have a [MacBook Pro 15" Late 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp644?locale=it_IT), where I have installed Windows 7 and Mac OS Lion in dual boot.

I have disabled Windows Pagefile because I have installed 16 GB RAM.

I cannot figure out why Windows is incredibly slower than Mac OS, especially after boot...

Is there something I can do to speed up boot in Windows? It seems to me that swap operations between hard disk and RAM are the bottle neck here...

Comment: 16GB RAM is not sufficient to disable the pagefile. Also, a small fixed pagefile size is much faster than a system modifiable one. If you're used to Mac, you'll find Windows file operations are much slower anyway, in comparison. An SSD would likely fix all your woes.

Comment: you should *never* disable the pagefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because your model is using a BIOS compatibility support module to support Windows in Boot Camp.

Macs have had an EFI firmware since they switched to the Intel platform in 2005, but Microsoft did not support EFI until Windows Vista, and Windows' EFI support was not really mature until Windows 8.

As a result, Apple implemented a BIOS emulation layer that kicks in automatically when the system is booting a non-Apple OS from a hybrid MBR partition table.  And because that layer was designed specifically to support Windows XP, it only implements the bare minimum BIOS features needed to run it.

Many of those features could be contributing to Windows feeling slower.  However, I would not characterize the difference as "incredible" the way you are seeing, so there may be more going on.

Among the BIOS features Apple did *not* implement are:

- SATA support.  Hard drives show up as IDE devices to Windows.
- Native Command Queuing (NCQ), a technique that allows SATA controllers to reorder I/O requests more efficiently rather than executing them in the order received.
- TRIM support for solid state drives (SSDs).  SSDs will slow down over time in Windows.
- Graphics switching (Windows is locked into using the discrete GPU on dual-GPU Macs).
- Boot support for USB, FireWire, and ExpressCard buses.  You can use these buses; you just can't boot from them.
- Optical S/PDIF output on the headphone jack.
- Limited ACPI support (only basic S1 and S3 sleep states are supported).  That means you lose processor features like dynamic frequency scaling and Turbo Boost (where the processor can disable a core for the sake of allowing another core to operate higher than its rated clock speed).

There are probably others too.  Those are just the ones I know about.

It should also be noted that this list only applies to Intel-based Macs made before 2012.  2012 and later Macs do not use the BIOS compatibility support module anymore.  Windows boots into EFI mode natively under the Mac's firmware and has all the features thereof.  Additionally, Apple has officially dropped support for Windows 7 as of 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think that upgrading to Windows 10 may speed up everything?

Comment: Windows 8 and 10 are more efficient all-around thanks to Microsoft's push to make it workable on low-powered tablet devices.  I still like Windows 7 better, but compared to Windows 10 it has a lot of bloat.

Comment: Ok. But my question refers to EFI support: if I install Windows 10 (which I think should be mature enough to work on EFI platforms), will Bootcamp continue to use this annoying BIOS emulation? Or, instead, Windows will work without any slowing middleware?

Comment: It will continue to use BIOS emulation. There is a way to get Windows booting natively in EFI, but on 2011 models with a dual GPU, you will not have video or sound without the BIOS layer. I have the same model as you (except mine is a 17") and I've tried every way there is to get it to work. Long story short, Windows can't deal with the gmux chip that Apple uses to switch between GPUs. Hybrid GPUs didn't exist for PCs in 2011. Apple invented that technology. Not surprisingly, native EFI boot works fine on the 2011 13" model and on MacBook Airs, because those models don't have dual GPUs.

Comment: If you want some of the more gory details on the gmux problem, you can read this post http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/2012/04/apple-macbook-pro-and-linux-hybrid_21.html.  It's for Linux on older models that use nVidia GPUs (yours is an ATI), but it it helps with understanding why it's not so simple as just flipping a switch, and why Apple decided to just not go down that road at all.